Build failed: Gradle build failed with unknown error in react native with eas
This error says below lines of autolinking_implementation.gradle file cause to make this error.could you please help me to solve this issue ?
// Object representing a maven repository.
    class MavenRepo {
      String url
      Object credentials
     String authentication

      MavenRepo(Object data) {
        this.url = data.url
        this.credentials = data.credentials
        this.authentication = data.authentication
      }
    }

**No such property: url for class: java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry
Possible solutions: key
**
I tried to build this react native project apk using eas. but it shows this build error. is there anyone who face this same issue or any method to solve this issue? I appreciate your help so much.
